# Stumped on a coding test - infuriating problem - suggestions please

Tags: algorithm

Let me start by saying I failed this challenge - it's already over, I didn't complete it, didn't get the job - so, don't tell me I am cheating by asking for help. I had 90 minutes to solve this.

BTW, if someone knows what this general class of problem is referred to as, please let me know.

Here is, as close as I can remember, the question.

Given a random sequence of characters from the set {'a', 'b'}.
Create 3 subsets from the sequence, example:
given aaaa
the subsets are:

1. a-a-aa
2. a-aa-a
3. aa-a-a

Each subset must have at least 1 'a'
If the sequence has zero 'a' , then list the possible groups of b (as above with 4 'a')
If the sequence has only 1 or 2 'a', then do not process (this is of course, trivial to test)

so, here is a slightly more advanced example:

Given "babbaaba"

The subsets would be:

1. ba-bbaab-a
2. bab-baab-a
3. babb-aab-a
4. babba-ab-a
5. ba-bbaa-ba
6. ba-bba-aba
7. bab-baa-ba
8. bab-ba-aba
   etc... (sorry, incomplete, don't need to bore you)

I cannot figure out a good way to solve this, I have looked at my (manual) process, over and over, and don't really see any algorithm emerging from it.

There was a limit to the maximum set size, perhaps 10,000 characters.  Presumably to indicate that use of recursion won't be a problem.

Comment: I think you might just need a double loop with some conditions. One loop for each "cut": first cut loops between 1 and the length of the sequence - 2 the second cut loops between the first cut + 1 and the length of the sequence - 1. Then inside the double loop, you can test all the constraints, if it's a valid subset add it to the list, if not continue.

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking it's basically a nested loop problem, except I get lost in the logic in the inner loop (the hard part).

Comment: With 3 subsets you need 2 breaks.  It is sometimes easier in this type of problem to place the breaks rather than trying to construct the subsets.

Comment: rossum: I don't understand what you are tyring to tell me.

Comment: I think what rossum is saying is that with this kind of problems, generating only the corrects subsets is often too difficult. Just generate anything with 2 breaks (or else depending on the problem), and then decide which are correct.

Comment: Ahh...so, just generate all sets of 3 groups, then test that they conform......Damn !   That's a great idea.  So obvious now that it has been given.    Aaaaarrrggghhhh !

Comment: You need to be careful that you count the a's efficiently. Trying all solutions is O(n^2) which is fine given the input size, but if you accidentally introduce another factor n, you'll be scuppered.

Comment: I can't figure out how to mark this as answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let string length is `n`. Make a list/array of length `n` and fill it with counts of "a" from the beginning upto i-th position. Overall "a" count is `na`.
*(It is possible to count "on the fly" without storing counts).*

```
b a b b a a b a  
0 1 1 1 2 3 3 4   na=4
```

You can place the first divider in any position between the first `1` and the first `na-1`

```
0 1 1 1 2 3 3 4
   ^ ^ ^ ^
```

Let the first divider goes after count `C`. You can place the second divider in any position after the first `C+1` and the first `na`.

```
0 1 1 1 2 3 3 4
     ^             C=1
         ^ ^ ^     possible second dividers

0 1 1 1 2 3 3 4
         ^         C=2
           ^ ^     possible second dividers
```

So you can generate all valid partitions with two nested for-loops.